# WebAPI: How to check if a user belongs to a group

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I have a WebApi service that uses Windows Authentication to authorize the users. The requirement is that a number of roles can make the same call, but the data returned can vary in some cases depending on the user group the client user belongs to.

**My question is:** How do I check if a user belongs to a specific user group?

Comment: It is currently unclear which group you're referring in the question. Would you please clarify with some code as to what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using roles from active directory, and that your user is well logged then a `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("")` should be works.

If you are using custom Authorize, then it will be custom.